# Generating 64 bit random values using AES-CTR

Tags: aes, pseudo-random-function, ctr

I need to generate 64 bit random values using AES-CTR.

Using fixed 64 bit plain text and sequential nonces can I assume the  higher order 64 bit output values of the AES-CTR to be random with a period of $2^{64}$?

Comment: Safe for what purpose? 64 bit by definition have no more then 64 bits of entropy.

Comment: In theory (output cannot be distinguished from random value) it is safe.  Assuming you have random nonce. If you can generate random nonce, you can generate radom value even without AES-CRT ...

Comment: Refined my  problem statement.Sorry for not making it clear in the first post

Comment: why do you need to generate them using AES-CTR?

Comment: @Richie Frame ,The platform which i use have accelerated AES implementation. Do you some other suggestions

Comment: Well, you can just use ECB mode and truncate, omitting any CTR specific code, CTR is more useful when you need output that is longer than the block length

Answer (score 1):

AES-CTR can be used as a random number generator if you don't mind that it never repeats the same 128 bit value - but the chances of that happening are minimal with a true RNG anyway.

In that case there is no need to have any plaintext though: you'd simply create the key stream (the encrypted counter values). If you only have a higher level cipher at your disposal you can simply do this by encrypting zero bytes.

If your key (the seed) is random then you can leave the IV/nonce set to zero as well and just start the counter (encoded as 16 bytes) at all-zeros.

---

If you'd use only 64 bitsof the 128 bit key stream generated by encrypting the counter then you would **not** have a repeated block within $2^{64}$ blocks. Although AES-CTR does have a period of $2^{128}$ *blocks* there is no guarantee that a value of 64 bit isn't repeated *earlier*.

Of course the cipher still has a *period* (as in, a long repeated sequence) of $2^{128}$ blocks as the counter will restart at zero when that happens, inconsequential of how many bits are actually used of each block.

Comment: I believe *Fortuna* PRNG, presented in [Practical Cryptography](https://www.schneier.com/books/practical_cryptography/) by N. Ferguson and B. Schneier is basically a complex CTR system.

Comment: It is meant _"If you'd use only 64 **bits** of the 128 bit key stream"_. Also: the AES key must be secret!